# NiFi: Writing code for ExecuteScript processor to combine multiple entries

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I have a NiFi flow (that works), that splits a massive spreadsheet into separate `csv`'s by company name.

E.g.

```
GetFile -> SplitText -> PartitionRecord -> MergeContent ->
UpdateAttribute -> PutFile
```

This puts out this, for example,

[image]

The problem comes with `csv`'s like this, where the same company is inputted slightly different:

[image]

I know I need to stick an `ExecuteScript` processor in here. I need to combine all such duplications into one file, without having to comb through several thousand lines to pick out each company that has been inputted in multiple ways.

I think this can be done easily with Groovy:

```
flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return
myAttr = flowFile.getAttribute('filename')
```

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: maybe you can just rename files before starting fetching them...

Comment: Yeah you try that on over a million lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine all duplications by using **[UpdateAttribute](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-update-attribute-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute/additionalDetails.html)** processor **[Adavanced](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/141774/how-to-generate-a-variable-under-conditions-for-an.html)** **Usage** and then store the files to directories..!!

**Flow:**

```
GetFile -> SplitText -> PartitionRecord -> UpdateAttribute-> MergeContent
 -> PutFile
```

***UpdateAttribute Configs:***

[image]

1. After PartitionRecord processor you are going to have partition field as attribute to the flowfile based on this attribute value you can write Rules like

   - Add new Rule with
     Conditions

   `${partition_field_name:toLower():contains("campbell")}`

   In the above rule we are checking if the partition_field_name attribute value contains campbell, like this way make use of **NiFI expression language** and add your logic to identify all kinds of partition values and perform desired actions.
2. If yes then we are adding flowfile attribute i.e

   **filename** with value as `campbell.csv`
3. Then in your Merge Content processor configure the below property as
   **Correlation Attribute Name** ->  **filename**
   Now all same kind of files are going to merge together.
4. If you are following this approach then you need to change `PutFile` configs
   **Conflict Resolution Strategy** because we are going to have same filename again.

**(or)**

1. It would be better if you make directory attribute in first UpdateAttribute based on the partition_value.
2. Then use MergeContent Processor with **correlation attribute name** as **directory**, Now we have merged all the files that belongs to same directory.
3. Then use another UpdateAttribute Processor to change the filename to Unique value like `UUID (or) timestamp..etc`.
4. Store the data using PutFile processor dynamically based on **directory attribute** value.

**Flow:**

```
  GetFile 
  -> SplitText 
  -> PartitionRecord 
  -> UpdateAttribute //add directory attribute 
  -> MergeContent 
  -> UpdateAttribute //change filename to ${UUID()}
  -> PutFile
```

Comment: When you say `partition_value` in the second section - are you changing the `${partition_field_...}` to `${partition_value_...}`?

Comment: @papelr, No, i mean to say based on `${partition_field_...}` attribute value create another attribute called `directory` and based on this directory attribute value store the **files in to those directories**. https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/191760/create-dynamic-partitions-based-on-flowfile-conten.html

Comment: Thanks! So if I do the second part, I don't need to do the `${partition_field_name:toLower():contains("campbell")}` ? Just to keep things straight in my own head

Comment: @papelr, Still you need to do `${partition_field_name:toLower():contains("campbell")}` to get directory attribute value, Then based on **directory attribute value Create/Save files** into those directories..!!